# SEO friendly URLs with Delphi ISAPI

Tags: delphi, seo, isapi

My customer wants me to get rid of the dll and ? & characters in the url and use SEO friendly urls.

How can I go about this URL - rewrite?

Currently I have something like:

http://www.ultimateholidayplanner.com/uhp.dll/AccList?PN=AccommodationSearch.htm

That needs to turn into something like:

http://www.ultimateholidayplanner.com/Accommodation/List.htm

Many thanks

Comment: What is the server? You may be able to get away with rewriting on the server instead of in the application.

Comment: Just FYI, I ended up using Helicon's URL Rewriter (free edition) with great success.

Answer (score 4):

Use II7 and download Microsoft URL rewrite module to change this behavior.

see [Using URL Rewrite module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/)

Regards

Comment: Thanks, but still running windows 2003. Upgrading will be a massive project on this server.

Comment: There are some isapi filters in codecentral and sourceforge for this question. It doesn't need to be in delphi because is server based and not application based.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change your code, you need just to use something like [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out. Looks promising and quite affordable. 

I've been trying to avoid regex all my life. Looks like I'm going to have to face it.

Answer (score 1):

ISAPI extensions can be mapped to the extension ".*" creating a wildcard extension mapping, and so catching any and every request to the site/virtual-dir. (especially with 'check that file exists' unselected)

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true

(if it might interest you: I found out working on [xxm](http://xxm.sourceforge.net/install.html#isapi))